# I have problems with the alignment of the table on my pages

Tags: tables, multirow

Any comment to improve the below code would be a great help.

```
\begin{document}
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{multirow}

\section[Temario de actividades]{Temario de actividades}

{\small\begin{longtable}{*{6}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{.18\linewidth}}}
\caption{Temario de actividades} \\
\toprule
\textsc{Versión}&\textsc{Horario} & \textsc{Tema} & \textsc{Nombre del Ejercicio} &
\textsc{Objetivo} & \textsc{Material}\\
\toprule
\endfirsthead
\toprule
\textsc{Versión}&\textsc{Horario} & \textsc{Tema} & \textsc{Nombre del Ejercicio} &
\textsc{Objetivo} & \textsc{Material}\\
\toprule
\endhead
\hline
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Continúa}\\
\bottomrule
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
    {\Large Versión A}& Día 1& \textbf{Bienvenida}& Presentación de los Facilitadores y objetivos del taller &  \\
    && \textbf{Integración grupal} & \emph{La telaraña} & Integración
grupal a través de los recursos personales & Una bola de estambre\\
          && \textbf{Presentación y acuerdos} & \emph{Brincón} & Establecer acuerdos de
convivencia grupales & Pelota de esponja.\\
          && \textbf{Automotivación}& \emph{Paseo por el bosque} & Fomentar la automotivación mediante el descubrimiento de las cualidades propias y la valoración positiva de los/as demás & Hojas, colores, dibujos de árbol, música\\
          && Retroalimentación & \emph{Esto es un abrazo} & cierre y
despedida& abrazos.\\
\midrule
{\Large Versión B}& Día 1 &\textbf{Presentación}& \emph{Brincón} & Que los participantes se presenten ante el grupo & Pelota de esponja\\  
\midrule
{\Large Versión A}& Día 2 & Respiración & \emph{Música y emociones} & Se recuerdan
acuerdos y recursos & Los acuerdos y recursos de la sesión
anterior,música.\\
          && \textbf{Emociones y tipos de comportamiento} & \emph{la emoción
derivada como protagonista} & Que cada participante reconozca sus
emociones con el objetivo de mejorar su comunicación y su
comportamiento ante sensaciones desagradables y agradables. & hojas
blancas, lápices y colores, información de emociones.\\
          && \textbf{Autoconcepto} & \emph{Dibujo de sí mismo y para los otros}
& reafirmar el conocimiento de uno mismo a través de la relación que
establecemos con los otros.& hojas y colores.\\
          && \emph{Retroalimentación} & devolución de comentarios
respecto a las actividades & \\
{\Large Versión B}& Día 2& \textbf{Auto-concepto y Toma de decisiones}& Árbol de las decisiones & Que los alumnos conozcan el proceso y los elementos básicos de toma de decisiones & Hojas blancas, lápices, colores, dibujo del árbol\\
&&\textbf{Autoestima y asertividad} & \emph{La Balanza} & Que el participante identifique sus fortalezas, habilidades como sus oportunidades y amenazas. Se toca también el tema de la asertividad. & Hojas blancas, colores, dibujos, frases irracionales, cuestionario de autoevaluación emocional.\\
\midrule
{\Large Versión A}& Día 3 & Inicio de sesión & \emph{Recapitulación} & retomar algunas
reflexiones de las sesiones anteriores& Diapositivas\\
          && \textbf{Autoestima y relaciones interpersonales} & \emph{lectura} & Autoestima,
confianza en uno mismo y las relaciones interpersonales. & Extracto
del cuento, e.j. el principito.\\
          && \emph{Percepción social y formas de vida} & Reflexionar sobre la forma de vida actual y
su relaciones interpersonales.& Discusión grupal\\
          &&\textbf{Manejo de tensión y estrés} & Identificar el tipo de situaciones
estresantes ante las que se encuentran en este momento de la vida. & Dar
a conocer los tipos de estresores y comportamientos  al afrontarlos. &
Anexo de tipos de comportamiento y estrés.\\
          && \emph{Collage} & Elaborar un collage en el que se represente la
forma en la que es percibida la sociedad que nos rodea: valores
actuales, creencias, estereotipos, etc\ldots. & Papel bond, plumones,
pegamento, tijeras,revistas, crayones. Preguntas de reflexión\\
          && Retroalimentación y cierre & los collage elaborados por
grupos se exponen y retroalimentan & collages.\\
\midrule
{\Large Versión B} &Día 3&\textbf{Emociones y tipos de comportamiento}& \emph{Reconociendo mis emociones} & Que el participante conozca e identifique sus emociones con el objetivo de mejorar su comunicación y su comportamiento & Papel bond, plumones, pegamento, tijeras, revistas, crayolas, canciones, preguntas de reflexión.\\
\midrule
{\Large Versión A}& Día 4 & \textbf{Comunicación asertiva} & \emph{Teléfono descompuesto} & Que
cada participante identifique las características y técnicas de una
comunicación asertiva & Diapositivas, plumones.\\
          && \textbf{Solución de conflictos y trabajo colaborativo} & \emph{El
nudo humano} & Reafirmar la importancia del trabajo colaborativo a
través de la comunicación no-verbal & Dinámica grupal.\\
          && Respiración y reflexión & \emph{Tensión y relajación} &
Distensión e incorporación del grupo a la introspección y reflexión de
sus objetivos y proyecto de vida & Música e instrucciones de la
actividad.\\
          && \textbf{Proyecto de vida} & \emph{El sentido de mi vida} & Reflexionar
sobre el proyecto de vida, logros, oportunidades, objetivos, a través
de una redacción y compartir algunos escritos al grupo & Dibujo del
árbol para proyecto de vida.\\
          && Cierre del taller &  Retroalimentación y despedida &
Comentarios y reflexiones finales.\\
\midrule
{\Large Versión B}&Día 4&\textbf{Comunicación asertiva y cierre} & \emph{collage} & Que el participante aprenda a comunicar sus emociones & Computadoras, video-comerciales, cuestionario, periódico y revistas, tijeras, pegamento, hojas blancas.\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Apart from your question you should notice that it is needless to say "`\section[x]{x}`", i.e. the result will be the same if you just leave the optional argument (in this case!).

Comment: Make sure of put a compilable code! In this example `\begin{document}` is missing.

Comment: `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` isn't necessary (it generally types `.pk` fonts  of bad quality (*pixelled*)), moreover you have loaded `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` that works better. (`Postscript`fonts)

Comment: @skpblack `fontenc` and `inputenc` deal with very different things; in particular `inputenc` has exactly *nothing* to do with fonts. The “pixellated” font problem is easily solved in various ways. For languages different from English, loading T1 *is* necessary.

Comment: @egreg If i remove `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` all work perfectly!! and i get fonts of excellent quality. I write in spanish. i don't know to explain why does it occur?

Comment: If you remove it, you may have problems with hyphenation for words with accented letters, as far as I know. You should keep T1 encoding and load, say `lmodern` — or any font T1-encoded that  you please.

Comment: @skpblack Let me guess: you're using MiKTeX. Look on the site for `CMSuper` or `CM-Super` and you'll find how to avoid the pixelated fonts.

Comment: @egreg I just installed `cm-super` package and solved problem with pixelated fonts. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to use the `ltablex` package here, which lets you have `tabularx` tables that can break across pages. Also the first two columns need not be that large, so I defined only the last 4 columns as `X` columns, redefined so as to be vertically centred, and  separated by a vertical spacing those rows that were not separated by a rule.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\setlength\aboverulesep{1ex}
\setlength\belowrulesep{1ex}
\setlength\defaultaddspace{1ex}
\usepackage{array, caption}
\captionsetup{labelfont = sc, textfont = it}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\small}m{#1}}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[nomarginpar, margin = 2.5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}


\section[Temario de actividades]{Temario de actividades}

{\small\setlength\tabcolsep{5pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ll*{4}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}}
\caption{Temario de actividades} \\
\toprule
\textsc{Versión}&\textsc{Horario} & \textsc{Tema} & \textsc{Nombre del Ejercicio} &
\textsc{Objetivo} & \textsc{Material}\\
\addlinespace[0.5ex]
\toprule
\addlinespace[2ex]
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{6}{c}{\textsc{\tablename~\thetable}\enspace (continuación)}\\
\addlinespace[2ex]
\toprule
\textsc{Versión}&\textsc{Horario} & \textsc{Tema} & \textsc{Nombre del Ejercicio} &
\textsc{Objetivo} & \textsc{Material}\\
\addlinespace[0.5ex]
\toprule
\endhead
\midrule
\multicolumn{6}{r}{Continúa}
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
    {\normalsize Versión A}& Día 1& \textbf{Bienvenida}& Presentación de los Facilitadores y objetivos del taller & \\
    && \textbf{Integración grupal} & \emph{La telaraña} & Integración
grupal a través de los recursos personales & Una bola de estambre\\
\addlinespace
          && \textbf{Presentación y acuerdos} & \emph{Brincón} & Establecer acuerdos de
convivencia grupales & Pelota de esponja.\\
\addlinespace
          && \textbf{Automotivación}& \emph{Paseo por el bosque} & Fomentar la automotivación mediante el descubrimiento de las cualidades propias y la valoración positiva de los/as demás & Hojas, colores, dibujos de árbol, música\\
\addlinespace
          && Retroalimentación & \emph{Esto es un abrazo} & cierre y
despedida& abrazos.\\
\cmidrule(lr){1-6}
{\normalsize Versión B}& Día 1 &\textbf{Presentación}& \emph{Brincón} & Que los participantes se presenten ante el grupo & Pelota de esponja\\
\midrule
{\normalsize Versión A}& Día 2 & Respiración & \emph{Música y emociones} & Se recuerdan
acuerdos y recursos & Los acuerdos y recursos de la sesión
anterior,música.\\
\addlinespace
          && \textbf{Emociones y tipos de comportamiento} & \emph{la emoción
derivada como protagonista} & Que cada participante reconozca sus
emociones con el objetivo de mejorar su comunicación y su
comportamiento ante sensaciones desagradables y agradables. & hojas
blancas, lápices y colores, información de emociones.\\
\addlinespace
          && \textbf{Autoconcepto} & \emph{Dibujo de sí mismo y para los otros}
& reafirmar el conocimiento de uno mismo a través de la relación que
establecemos con los otros.& hojas y colores.\\
\addlinespace
          && \emph{Retroalimentación} & Devolución de comentarios
respecto a las actividades & \\
\cmidrule(lr){1-6}
{\normalsize Versión B}& Día 2& \textbf{Auto-concepto y Toma de decisiones}& Árbol de las decisiones & Que los alumnos conozcan el proceso y los elementos básicos de toma de decisiones & Hojas blancas, lápices, colores, dibujo del árbol\\
\addlinespace
&&\textbf{Autoestima y asertividad} & \emph{La Balanza} & Que el participante identifique sus fortalezas, habilidades como sus oportunidades y amenazas. Se toca también el tema de la asertividad. & Hojas blancas, colores, dibujos, frases irracionales, cuestionario de autoevaluación emocional.\\
\midrule
{\normalsize Versión A}& Día 3 & Inicio de sesión & \emph{Recapitulación} & retomar algunas
reflexiones de las sesiones anteriores& Diapositivas\\
\addlinespace
          && \textbf{Autoestima y relaciones interpersonales} & \emph{Lectura} & Autoestima,
confianza en uno mismo y las relaciones interpersonales. & Extracto
del cuento, e.j. el principito.\\
\addlinespace
          && \emph{Percepción social y formas de vida} & Reflexionar sobre la forma de vida actual y
su relaciones interpersonales.& Discusión grupal\\
\addlinespace
          &&\textbf{Manejo de tensión y estrés} & Identificar el tipo de situaciones
estresantes ante las que se encuentran en este momento de la vida. & Dar
a conocer los tipos de estresores y comportamientos al afrontarlos. &
Anexo de tipos de comportamiento y estrés.\\
\addlinespace
          && \emph{Collage} & Elaborar un collage en el que se represente la
forma en la que es percibida la sociedad que nos rodea: valores
actuales, creencias, estereotipos, etc\ldots. & Papel bond, plumones,
pegamento, tijeras,revistas, crayones. Preguntas de reflexión\\
\addlinespace
          && Retroalimentación y cierre & los collage elaborados por
grupos se exponen y retroalimentan & collages.\\
\cmidrule(lr){1-6}
{\normalsize Versión B} &Día 3&\textbf{Emociones y tipos de comportamiento}& \emph{Reconociendo mis emociones} & Que el participante conozca e identifique sus emociones con el objetivo de mejorar su comunicación y su comportamiento & Papel bond, plumones, pegamento, tijeras, revistas, crayolas, canciones, preguntas de reflexión.\\
\midrule
{\normalsize Versión A}& Día 4 & \textbf{Comunicación asertiva} & \emph{Teléfono descompuesto} & Que
cada participante identifique las características y técnicas de una
comunicación asertiva & Diapositivas, plumones.\\
\addlinespace
          && \textbf{Solución de conflictos y trabajo colaborativo} & \emph{El
nudo humano} & Reafirmar la importancia del trabajo colaborativo a
través de la comunicación no-verbal & Dinámica grupal.\\
\addlinespace
          && Respiración y reflexión & \emph{Tensión y relajación} &
Distensión e incorporación del grupo a la introspección y reflexión de
sus objetivos y proyecto de vida & Música e instrucciones de la
actividad.\\
\addlinespace
          && \textbf{Proyecto de vida} & \emph{El sentido de mi vida} & Reflexionar
sobre el proyecto de vida, logros, oportunidades, objetivos, a través
de una redacción y compartir algunos escritos al grupo & Dibujo del
árbol para proyecto de vida.\\
\addlinespace
          && Cierre del taller & Retroalimentación y despedida &
Comentarios y reflexiones finales.\\
\cmidrule(lr){1-6}
{\normalsize Versión B}&Día 4&\textbf{Comunicación asertiva y cierre} & \emph{collage} & Que el participante aprenda a comunicar sus emociones & Computadoras, video-comerciales, cuestionario, periódico y revistas, tijeras, pegamento, hojas blancas.\\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Here are the first 2 pages, out of 4:

[image]

[image]